# tkinter event x y mouse position wrong value only when mouse movement up?

Tags: python, tkinter, events

I´ve found some questions about similar problems. But not right the same like my problem.

If my mouse is moved left or right or down all works fine. But if I move the mouse fast up the x y position is sometimes wrong! To describe the problem in the best way I have a short video for you. If I move the mouse very slow up there is no problem. Why? Left, right and down the mouse speed there is no problem.

[Short video](https://www.loom.com/share/96a05b356e55454ebc8fdc6bca20fcdf)

Here is my python code:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('2000x600')

# Textausgabe erzeugen
label1 = tk.Label(root, text="Hallo Welt!",
                        fg="red",
                        bg="orange",
                        font=("times", 25, "bold", "italic"))
label1.place(x=1, y=1)

#Grafik einbetten
bild1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="biene.png")
label2 = tk.Label(root, image=bild1)
label2.place(x=1,y=100)


def motion(event):
    global pos_x, pos_y, r_pos_x, r_pos_y
    pos_x = event.x
    pos_y = event.y

    label2.place(x=pos_x-60,y=pos_y-110)
    print('{}, {}'.format(pos_x, pos_y))
```

[image]

Comment: For something like this, using a `Canvas` would be a much better approach. `Canvas` is designed for basic 2D drawings and games, unlike `place()`, which is only designed to put widgets into a window. Using `Canvas` will make this code much less problematic, and wouldn't flicker.

Comment: thank you very much. I´m on the right way now. It works fine. Now i have to find something to get the x y coordinates from the image to calculate the position because i use .move from canvas...

Comment: You can use `canvas.coords(image)` to get a list of coordinates for `image`. `canvas.coords()` works on anything in a `Canvas`.

Comment: Thank you @SylvesterKruin - i used your solution. it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my solution. Thanks to all.

```
from tkinter import *

canvas_width = 2000
canvas_height =600

master = Tk()
master.geometry('2000x600')


image1 = "biene.png"
photo1 = PhotoImage(file=image1)
width1 = photo1.width()
height1 = photo1.height()
canvas1 = Canvas(width=width1, height=height1)
canvas1.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH) # <--- Make your canvas expandable.
x = (width1)/2.0
y = (height1)/2.0
item = canvas1.create_image(x, y, image=photo1)



def motion(event):
    global pos_x, pos_y
    global item
    global item_x, item_y

    item_pos = canvas1.coords(item)
    item_x = item_pos[0]
    item_y = item_pos[1]
    #print("item pos = " + str(item_x) + " " + str(item_y))

    pos_x = event.x
    pos_y = event.y

    

    canvas1.move(item, pos_x - item_x, pos_y - item_y) # <--- Use Canvas.move method.
    #canvas1.delete(item)
    #item = canvas1.create_image(pos_x, pos_y, image=photo1)

    print('{}, {}'.format(pos_x, pos_y))
    print("Coordinates of the object are:", canvas1.coords(item))
        
        
master.bind('<Motion>', motion)
mainloop()
```

Comment: Please accept your answer, so that other users know that the question has been answered satisfactorily.

Answer (score 1):

`(event.x, event.y)` is the coordinate of the mouse at the time of the event, relative to the upper left corner of the widget. You may also get the coordinate in the widgets label1 or label2.

Try to use `(event.root_x, event.root_y)` which is the coordinate of the mouse at the time of the event, relative to the upper left corner of the screen.

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1000x600')

# Textausgabe erzeugen
label1 = tk.Label(root, text="Hallo Welt!",
                        fg="red",
                        bg="orange",
                        font=("times", 25, "bold", "italic"))
label1.place(x=1, y=1)

#Grafik einbetten
bild1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="biene.png")
label2 = tk.Label(root, image=bild1)
label2.place(x=1, y=100)


def motion(event):
    global pos_x, pos_y, r_pos_x, r_pos_y

    pos_x = event.x_root    # Revised
    pos_y = event.y_root    # Revised

    label2.place(x=pos_x-60, y=pos_y-110)
    print(event.widget)     # Check which widget
    print('{}, {}'.format(pos_x, pos_y))

root.bind("<Motion>", motion)

root.mainloop()
```